# Indexing and constraints for uniqueness/relationship with primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, rdbms, database-performance

I need to clear the following in my head.

When I create a table with no primary key or unique constraint I get a flat file.
When I create a primary key a primary index is created as a result and it is this index that maintains the uniqueness of the primary key, right? So I can not add a duplicate value.
So if I create an index on any column does this enforce the column to have unique values? Or that depends on using the keyword `UNIQUE` for the index creation?
Finally every time I declare a column having a `UNIQUE` constraint does that mean that an index is created and so these actions are interchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If we create an index on any column, that does not enforce that a
   column to have unique values. There can be duplicate values in the
   column, but those will be indexed.
2. Unique values in column will be enforced by using the keyword UNIQUE
   for the column.
3. The differences between UNIQUE column and Primary key column is -
   UNIQUE key column can hold NULL value in one and only one of the
   table row. Primary key column will not hold null value.
4. When a UNIQUE column is created, then implicitly an index is
   created. But when an Index is created on a column that does not mean
   all the row value for the column will be UNIQUE. So they are not
   interchangeable.

Comment: So what is the purpose of `UNIQUE` constraint if `INDEX UNIQUE` does exactly the same job?

Answer (score 1):

> When I create a primary key a primary index is created as a result and
>   it is this index that maintains the uniqueness of the primary key,
>   right?

Yes, though the primary key index is not exactly the same as a unique index (it has certain priorities over 'regular' unique indexes.

> So if I create an index on any column does this enforce the column to
>   have unique values? Or that depends on using the keyword UNIQUE for
>   the index creation?

An index on a table column does not automatically constrain that columns values to be unique, unless you explicitly use a `UNIQUE INDEX`.

> Finally every time I declare a column having a UNIQUE constraint does
>   that mean that an index is created and so these actions are
>   interchangeable?

A unique constraint is created via a `UNIQUE INDEX`. They are one and the same thing.

Comment: So any time I create declare a `UNIQUE` on a column I create a new index?

Comment: @Cratylus - yes, `UNIQUE` in that context is short for `UNIQUE KEY`. The MySQL dev's made the KEY part optional, for ease of use.

Comment: So if for example I declare a `INDEX UNIQUE` on columns `A`,`B` it is exactly the same as creating a composite primary key? This also relates to cascades i.e. referential integrity or only on uniqueness?

Comment: Its not **exactly** the same as creating a primary key, but the uniqueness constraint imposed by both is exactly the same.